# How to check the Android manifest file for the libraries included in the application Project Android Studio?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play-console

I have uploaded the Application to the Google Play console and they gave me warning to update the app to the TargetSDKversion 26 or above which i have already did in the Adnroid Manifest File. However, I am concerned about the Manifest File of the External libraries i am using like glide and all.

is there a way to check the Android Manifest File of the SDK and other libraries include in the project?

I want to know the Target version they are using. Can i check it on Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

You have to update the targetSdkVersion in your app's build.gradle file. The build.gradle file takes precedent over the manifest.  If you still want to look at what is being merged into your manifest from external dependencies you can open your app's manifest file and click on the merged manifest tab at the bottom.

Comment: I have set the Target SDK version of the App in the main gradle to 26. But today i get the error that you must update the TargetSDK version.

Suppose i am using the barcode scanner dependencies and if their target SDK is 25 will it cause any problem?

Comment: So what could be the problem? I have to updated the dependencies which is targetting below 26?

Comment: what does it mean? (Included in merge, but did not contribute any elements)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question as posed above.

Answer (score -1):

On Android Studio, simply go to the "Merged Manifest" by going to your `AndroidManifest.xml` in app module then navigate to it and choose the library you want to check its target version

Comment: can i manually edit the target SDK version of the dependencies?

Comment: Yes, if you imported them to your project as modules.

Comment: Look into this question i have posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487609/any-update-of-firebase-dispatcher-library-for-targeting-api-26-or-more

Comment: Doesn't answer the question as posed above.